# Uber iOS SDK - How to implement custom Uber Ride Request Button

Tags: ios, swift, uber-api

I'm working with the Uber SDK for iOS. How do I implement a custom Uber Rides Request button in Swift? I don't want to use the standard button that Uber uses in their docs. I want to design my own UI for it. [Reference](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/ride-request-buttons)

Comment: can you show some sample which type you need

Answer (score 3):

You can create a ride request button in swift using the following:

```
let button = RideRequestButton()
let ridesClient = RidesClient()
let pickupLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 37.787654, longitude: -122.402760)
let dropoffLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 37.775200, longitude: -122.417587)
let builder = RideParametersBuilder().setPickupLocation(pickupLocation).setDropoffLocation(dropoffLocation, nickname: "Somewhere", address: "123 Fake St.")
ridesClient.fetchCheapestProduct(pickupLocation: pickupLocation, completion: {
    product, response in
    if let productID = product?.productID {
        builder = builder.setProductID(productID)
        button.rideParameters = builder.build()
        button.loadRideInformation()
}
})
```

What do you want to customize (product, pickup, dropoff)? Depending what you want to customize you can see the examples in the docs here: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/ride-request-buttons

Comment: I want to customize the UI. I don't want to use the black or white version that is explained in the docs. Basically, how do I add the function target for Uber to a custom button?

Comment: You can use a deep link in this case and then you can use whatever button style you want. See the example here: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/deep-linking-action-setpickup

Comment: Hey @DustinWhittle can i get some help here, please look at the problem statement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282763/uber-deeplink-and-universal-url-crashes-android-application

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the deeplink functionality, you can use the `RequestDeeplink` class. Something like:

```
func setup() {
    let rideParameters = RideParametersBuilder().build()
    let deeplink = RequestDeeplink(rideParameters: rideParameters)
    let button = UIButton()
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}

func buttonAction() {
     deeplink.execute()
}
```